# Sync requests in migration from Monolithic to Microservice architecture

Tags: web-services, apache-kafka, architecture, microservices

I have a web service based on monolithic architecture. I want to migrate to microservices architecture. Service can respond both async and sync way. Sync way obvious request -> response. Async way is depending to client's polling and kafka topic(both can be used).

My question is I want to respond fully async. Maybe any idea to how can I support sync requests. I mean internally async with or without kafka (any tech stack suggestion also will be okay) but client will not notice it is async?

Thank you in advance. I can also provide more cases according to questions.

.......................................

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Let's imagine you have service A and service B, A makes sync request to B. What should be async here?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest what is to go into a wait loop and periodically check to see if the async has responded.  This is moving the resources/complexity from the client to the server.  You will not see any advantage in async using this architecture, it will just add complexity and costs as you will need larger servers with more complexity to hide the work of blocking until async completes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable input. So is it okay to support sync requests between several (4-5) microservices without converting it async? Isn't it worth to hide async because of generated complexity? Btw monolithic version has really high performance (Not maintainable anymore) I am just afraid of several network call's will destroy this.
Thank you again for sharing your experience, it is nice to ask someone who is really experienced  :)

Comment: network calls can get really expensive.  If you already have high-performance, why are you looking to move away from a monolith?  Are you having organizational scaling issues that you are trying to solve?  Or are you building microservices because "that's how people are building things"?  You may want to think about refactoring your monolith if you aren't solving problems like organizational scaling and independent scaling of components.